# How to mine Specified from text in python?

Tags: python, variables, text, storing-information

I have an output from a program as a text like:

```
------------
Action specified: GetInfo

Gathering information...

Reported chip type: 2307

Reported chip ID: 98-DE-94-93-76-50

Reported firmware version: 1.08.10

------------
```

But I must save just, `Reported chip type: value "2307"` in a variable.
how it's possible?

Comment: I tried to use NLTK but ... i could n't

Comment: But there is no *value*  within your text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would usually do something like this with [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

```
import re
match = re.search('Reported chip type:\s(?P<chip_type>\d+)', my_text)
chiptype = int(match.group('chip_type'))     

>>> print chiptype
2307
```

In your case though, it's probably simple enough to just use a couple [splits](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
chiptype = int(my_text.split('Reported chip type:', 1)[-1].split('\n')[0].strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can read the file and have read it into a variable named `text`:

```
for line in text:
    if line.startswith("Reported chip type:"):
        _, chiptype = line.split(':')
        break

print chiptype
```

This will put the first instance of "Reported chip type:"'s value into `chiptype`.

Your output looks like this:

```
 2307
```

Notice that there is a leading space. We can convert this to an `int` if you know it is always an `int` you can do this:  `chiptype = int(chiptype)`. If it's just a string, you can strip of the leading space: `chiptype = chiptype.strip()`

Comment: Because your text doesn't match what you posted. `chiptype` is only defined if your line starts with `Reported chip type:` (no spaces or other characters)